# GLMM Convergence issues with lme4

Tags: r, dataframe, lme4, poisson

I am modelling the number of jobs over month 1-112 (taken over ~10 years) for each Hospital. The number of jobs over time vary depending on the hospital so I have defined the following multilevel model as a starting point:

```
glmer.nb(Jobs ~ 1 + Region + Month + ( Month | factor(Region)),
                     data = df_month_region, 
                     family = poisson(link = "log"))
```

My data looks very similar to this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Region = rep(1:14, each=112),
  Month = rep(seq(1,112,1),14),
  Job = rpois(112*14, 0.7)
)
```

I would like to know:

1) Does modelling my data in this format makes sense? Would it make more sense to have a column for year and month separately?

2) How do I overcome this error: "Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.00361688 (tol = 0.001, component 1)Model is nearly unidentifiable: very large eigenvalue"? - I have followed the steps here: https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/33653_57fc7b8e5d484c909b615d8633c01d51.html as commonly recommended on this site but I am starting to think the underlying problem lies perhaps with how I have setup my dataframe or my model?

Comment: Pablo has a good point in his answer, but I have a few points I'd like to clarify. Are you interested in just the effect of Months, and the differences between hospitals is just noise? Or are you interested in how the jobs differ across both variables?

Comment: I am interested in the effect of the number of jobs over time, and want to capture the variation of jobs over time within each hospital, hence the random effect. I also have the region the hospital is in but I am unsure how to use that in the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so based on the additional information you provided in your comment, I'm going to expand upon Pablo's answer. Since you are really only interested in the change in number of jobs over time, your only fixed effect should be Month. Now, you also say that you have the different hospitals and the regions those hospitals are in. That means that you need to have a nested random effects structure, where you have different hospitals that belong to the different regions. You can read more about nested random effects here:

http://errickson.net/stats-notes/vizrandomeffects.html

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228800/crossed-vs-nested-random-effects-how-do-they-differ-and-how-are-they-specified

So, the final model that you should run will look like this:

```
job_model <- glmer(Jobs ~ Month + (1|Region/Hospital),
                     data = df_month_region, 
                     family = poisson(link = "log"))
```

In order to see if `Month` improves the model significantly, you should also fit the following model for comparison.

```
job_model_null <- glmer(Jobs ~ 1 + (1|Region/Hospital),
                     data = df_month_region, 
                     family = poisson(link = "log"))
```

And then you compare them with the likelihood ratio test using the `anova()` function like so:

```
anova(job_model, job_model_null)
```

EDIT:
If you wish to fit a random slope for Month to the random effects, it would look like this:

```
job_model <- glmer(Jobs ~ Month + (1+Month|Region/Hospital),
                     data = df_month_region, 
                     family = poisson(link = "log"))
```

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer! So are you saying if I expect the number of jobs over time to have a different intercept and slope within Hospitals (that are nested in regions) I should use (Jobs|Region/Hospitals)? And use your model if I only expect a different intercept? Does this logic also apply for negative binomial models? (ie glmer.nb() in lme4)

Comment: Thank you! Would you mind clarifying why my formulation of ( Month | factor(Region)) did not make sense? In Ben Bolker's guide (https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v067i01 page4), they modeled reaction time like this: lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy), so I used the same logic but my data was measured in months instead of days

Comment: I'm sorry, there was a typo in my earlier comment. The correct random slope model would include (1+Month|Region/Hospitals)

Answer (score 1):

If  **Region**  is a string lme4 detects automatically that is a factor. Your model have random intercepts and random slopes. Month as random slope have not many sense, month is also a factor or block variable.

Mixed Effects model:

```
glmer(Jobs ~ 1  + ( 1 | Region) + (1| Month),
                 data = df_month_region, 
                 family = poisson(link = "log"))
```

Fixed Effects model:

```
glm(Jobs ~ 1  + Region + Month,
                 data = df_month_region, 
                 family = poisson(link = "log"))
```

Month and Region should be string.